No such file error loading pytorch model on c++
I am working on an AI for an open source game. But when I try to load the pt file (the pytorch model) onto c++ using <torch/script.h> library, the program fails to execute torch::jit::script::Module model = torch::jit::load(filePath). The error I get is: main: Exception caught : open file failed because of errno 2 on fopen: No such file or directory, file path.
The obvious would be to check if the file path is correct, but it is. I know this because on an isolated environment, just a c++ main file using cmake, I am able to execute the exact same lines of code and the model is loaded and able to be used. Additionally, I am able to open the pt file using fstream on the game environment.
Any help would be so much appreciated, this is for my thesis. Thank you in advance!

You probably need to learn a bit more about C++ and CMake. torch::jit::load happens at runtime, but CMake works at build time. Those could even happen on completely different computers, but most likely for you it's just different working directories.
